# Bash Script to start a process on a remote Linux Machine and keep it detached from the starting server

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm new to Linux (Red Hat) and I'm trying to automate the Eggplant tests I've come up with for our GUI based software.  This will be run nightly.

I'll be running the base script on server 001.  It will copy over the latest version of our software to a remote PC which is serving as test bench then it's to kick off a Bash script on the test bench which configures the environment then starts up the software.
I've tried:

> ssh test@111.111.111.002 'bash -s' < testConfig.sh
>
> ssh test@111.111.111.002 'bash -s testConfig.sh < /dev/nul > testConfig.log 2>&1 &'
>
> ssh -X test@111.111.111.002 'testConfig.sh'

First one just fails, the second tries to start the software but instead of running on the test bench it tries running on the server.  Of course with the third one it opens up windows on the server and runs the software; but I need the display on the test bench not the server.

Comment: do you want to redirect the output to somefile. Something like ., ssh -X test@111.111.111.002 'testConfig.sh>>file.txt' ??

Comment: No, I just want to run the startup script like a user was sitting at the remote station doing it.  The Eggplant test system is on a third server and connects to the remote test station via an x11vnc connection.

Comment: Do you need the `-X`? If you need an X11 tunnel open for the program to run, you can't detach by definition: The X connection will break as soon as the SSH connection goes down.

Comment: ...to make one of the earlier ones used, you'll need to configure the DISPLAY and (possibly) Xauthority setup to point to the test-bench X server you want it to target. That configuration is host-specific, and somewhat out-of-scope for Stack Overflow.

Comment: The -X was something I tried, but it ended up running the display on the wrong machine.  But the machine it came up on is also on our Windows network and I didn't want that crossover for nightly testing.  A coworker suggested adding the 'DISPLAY' option like you suggested (see below) and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A coworker happened by and saw my difficulty and suggested this, and it worked:

> ssh user@1.1.1.1 'setenv DISPLAY :0.0 && testConfig.sh'

Comment: If `setenv` worked, you're using csh, not bash -- they're completely different (not-at-all-compatible-with-each-other) shells.

Answer (score -1):

Try below and let us know. Using double quotes instead of single quotes.

`ssh user@1.1.1.1 "bash -s" < ./testConfig.sh`

make sure testConfig.sh is in the directory from where you are ssh'ing else use absolute path name for e.g. /home/qwe/testConfig.sh

Please also mention the error you are getting if any.

Comment: There's no difference whatsoever between `"bash -s"` and `'bash -s'`; they both convert to the exact same C string, so by the time `ssh` is started, it doesn't even have any way of telling which of the two was used.